# vb6 winsock connection instead unlimited clients per devide to be reduced to 2

Tags: vb6, 2d, winsock

Hello i`ve got a client/server 2d mmorgp game plaing by us frinds and due to to many copies of the client i`ve tried to reduce the client to be opened to 2 clients per device but is not per device its on the network 2 clients . maybe i do somewhere mistake.

```
Sub ConnectionRequestCon(ByVal requestID As Long)
On Error Resume Next
Dim check As Integer
Dim LoggedOn As Integer
Dim NewIndex As Integer
Dim RandomCheck As Integer
NewIndex = GetFreeIndex
LogOutProcedure NewIndex
RandomizeConLandLaunch NewIndex
Load Main.Server(NewIndex)
Load Main.EngageTimer(NewIndex)
Main.Server(NewIndex).Accept requestID
AddServerLogText NewIndex & ": Connected [" & Main.Server(NewIndex).RemoteHostIP & "]"
RandomCheck = RandomNumber(1000, 30000)
SetConAuthNumber NewIndex, RandomCheck
Main.Server(NewIndex).SendData "1,Welcome To Xiaspora - " & TotalLogedInUsers & " Users Online" &             Chr(13) & "34," & RandomCheck & Chr(13)
DoEvents
Do
check = check + 1
If Main.Server(check).State = 7 And Main.Server(check).RemoteHostIP =     Main.Server(NewIndex).RemoteHostIP Then LoggedOn = LoggedOn + 1
Loop Until check = Main.Server.Count
If LoggedOn >= 4 Then CloseCon NewIndex 'with the number 4 reduce the clients per device . when is 7     is unlimited
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looping `check` from 1 to `Main.Server.Count` and check *each* `Main.Server(check).State` but you probably have unloaded socket controls already.

You have `On Error Resume Next` at the top of the code but consider that similar code like this

```
Dim lCount As Long
On Error Resume Next
If 1 / 0 > 0 Then lCount = lCount + 1
Debug.Print lCount
```

. . . prints `1` i.e. from If expression OERN gets "next" statement *inside* the If, no matter that it's on the *same* line as the If expression.

Now consider what happens when `Main.Server(check).State` is checked on an unloaded control. Because of the OERN this one *will* be counted towards `LoggedOn` which is clearly not what you want to do.

With OERN in this case you might want to reverse the If expression like this

```
If Main.Server(check).State <> 7 Then
    '--- do nothing
ElseIf Main.Server(check).RemoteHostIP = Main.Server(NewIndex).RemoteHostIP Then
    LoggedOn = LoggedOn + 1
End If
```

. . . so that when accessing `Main.Server(check).State` bombs out it "enters" the If block and there is nothing to do there.